# Creating computer group in Azure LAWS with Kusto Query

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to create Computer group for Update management from log analytics saved search but can't figure it totally out.

When using this query, it will list all computer that has "test" in their name. Working fine, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

```
 Heartbeat
| where Computer contains "test"
| distinct Computer
```

But when I want to add computers by their specific name, I get error. Any this how can I get result by using computers specific names?

[[image: Error message[1]]

```
Heartbeat
| where Computer contains "test" and "test2" and "test3"
| distinct Computer
```

Also tried with "or" "has" "==" but could not get it working.

Comment: you want to list the computers with their real name? like computer1, computer2?

Comment: Ye, I  want add real names to query and it would list as results those real names

Comment: You can use "in" operator, please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the [in operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/inoperator).

Sample query looks like below:

```
Heartbeat
| where Computer in ("test", "test2", "test3")
| distinct Computer
```